# How do I batch convert a gif to apng using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, png, gif, apng

How to I convert a gif to an animated png file without increasing the file size. When I convert the gif on ezgif it increases the files size. And what would be the for loop command that would convert multiple files? I have all the files in numerical file names.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much you can do about file size increase. APNG files are going to be bigger than GIFs. That's the file format, and that's how it works.

The simplest way to convert a GIF to APNG using ffmpeg is to run the command `ffmpeg -i input.gif output.apng`.

If you want to do it in a loop you can use bash or any other shell or programming language.

Here's an example of converting all `.gif` files into `.apng` with bash and ffmpeg:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in input*.gif
do
    ffmpeg -i $file ${file%.gif}.apng
done
```

If you have files with numeric names like `input1.gif`, `input2.gif`, ..., `input100.gif` you can use the following piece of code:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
    ffmpeg -i "input$i.gif" "input$i.apng"
done
```